# Is there a way we can test UI with all its aspects comparing Figma designs to iOS and Android application? Is there any tool for that?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, figma, gui-testing

I need to compare exact designs made in Figma to the Android and iOS application UI, but it is difficult to compare Figma UI with Android and iOS application directly to test it properly.
As of now just doing it manually by comparing screens one by one.

Tried to search online for any tool but not able to find anything.